# Why do we need mavros?

Tags: mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone please explain in simple words, why do we need mavros ? I have been trying to understand mavros form the documentation but did not understand it completely.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237401/why-do-we-need-mavros?/) by [muscles](https://answers.ros.org/users/24958/muscles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

mavros makes it possible to communicate with a MavLink autopilot via ROS topics

It does this by publishing sensor data and status from the autopilot as ROS topics, and by subscribing to other ROS topics for commands, and then sending those commands to the autopilot.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0